# Calling Python script from Java code using Runtime.exec() : ImportError: No module named sklearn

Tags: java, python, intellij-idea

I Have a Java program that calls a python script. That python script has the following imports

```
 import numpy as np
 from sklearn import metrics
```

On my mac, i already have python 2.7, i now installed python 3.7
I also installed numpy, scipy and sklearn modules using pip3.

In Intellij, i selected the python 3.7 interpreter and Java1.8 for my project

When i run the java program which calls python script using the command

```
 Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("python /mydir/report.py");
```

i get this error

```
ImportError: No module named sklearn
```

My suspicion is that somehow intellij is using python 2.7 and python 3.7. The reason is when i run the python script directly in pyCharm using python2.7, i get the same error but not with 3.7

Please help resolve this, i already went through all the related SO questions and were not helpful for this situation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using 'python3' :

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("python3 /mydir/report.py");
```

Or alternatively, you can try:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("python", "/mydir/report.py"); /*Or python3*/
Process process = pb.start();
```

For detailed usage of ProcessBuilder : https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/lang/processbuilder/java-lang-processbuilder-example/

Comment: Thank you very much. executing with python3 solved.

Comment: This is my first answer here... Glad I could help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are using the correct version of python. In some OS's, python3.x is called on the command line as `python3` and therefore you will need to change your `exec` code to 
`"python3 /mydir/report.py"`.

If you are using python3, `pip` will be shipped with the install, and therefore, you may also need to run `pip install -U scikit-learn`.

Answer (score -1):

The answer is in your question: No module named sklearn.
Try to install sklearn :

```
pip install -U scikit-learn
```

Comment: In the question, OP said that they did.