# Include a python package in a Java project

Tags: java, python, intellij-idea, process

I have a Java Project in which i included a python script through the
code:

```
    try {
        mProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("python pythonScript.py");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }
```

Problem is the python code needs a python site package to run ,

While running the python code alone in Pycharm it works correctly
but intellij cant understand the code fully

these are the imports am trying to include in intellij

import ply.lex as lex

import ply.yacc as yacc

Comment: Can this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/56964414/10416835

Comment: Leverage `jython` ?

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand completely your question, but maybe this can help you.

```
ArrayList<String> cmdLd = new ArrayList<String>();
cmdLd.add("python3");
cmdLd.add("pythonScript.py");
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(cmdLd);
Process process = pb.start();
process.getOutputStream().close();
process.waitFor();
```